# Infinite loop preventing root.mainloop() from executing- Python

Tags: python, tkinter, automation, scheduler

Hey guys this is probably stupid but i just cant find a way around it... Im trying to run my python code on a daily interval and im using schedule to do so. However, it prevents `root.mainloop()`from being reached as theres an infinite loop right before. This is the website https://pypi.org/project/schedule/
If there is a better way to "schedule" my code to run at a certain time on certain days, i would greatly appreciate it! this is the sample code below.

```
def job():
    print("I am doing this job!")


schedule.every().monday.at("11:21").do(job)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("22:00").do(job)
schedule.every().thursday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().friday.at("14:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is an [example](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/background-execution.html) in the official document to run the while loop in a child thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [example](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/background-execution.html) in the official document to run the while loop in a child thread.

Below is another simple example:

```py
import threading
...

def check_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=check_schedule, daemon=True).start()

root.mainloop()
```

If `job()` is not a long-running task, `after()` can be used instead of while loop:

```py
...

def check_schedule():
    schedule.run_pending()
    root.after(1000, check_schedule)

check_schedule() # start the loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where would I put in the line of code ```schedule.every().thursday.at("09:28").do(send_email())``` so that it sends the email on a specific time?

Comment: @kyle Same as how you schedule `job()`.